# Export content query web part from SharePoint 2013 and import it in o365 SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, export, import, office-365, cewp

I have created a page with CEWP. I need to export them from on premise version to the O365 version. Please guide me.

Comment: Do you need to export only that webpart or the whole page?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export the whole page:

1. Using SP Designer , open the on premise SharePoint site.
2. Now go to library where the page is present.
3. Select that page and Click Export file and save it in your local disk.
4. Now open the o365 site in SP designer and navigate to the library where you need to add that page.
5. Click import file and select the page from local disk.

If you want to export only the CQWP:

1. Go to the on premise site and Edit the page.
2. On the edit webpart pane, click **Export**. Save it to local disk
3. Now go to o365 site, navigate to the page where you want to add the CQWP.
4. Edit the page , click on Add webpart.
5. Now below categories you can see Upload a webpart. Browse and select the CQWP from local disk. Click Upload.
6. Now the webpart will be visible in Imported Webparts category. now you can add it inside any webpart zone.